# USB Boot / Install freezes after initializing

Tags: system-installation

So I decided to try and load Ubuntu 17.04 up last night from a USB I created using Rufus. Grub2 loads up just fine, allowing me to choose to run Ubuntu from USB or install it. Choosing either method results in the process freezing and requiring a restart.

[image: Picture or error]

After some searching, I found that I could get around this by setting an install parameter to `acpi=off`, allowing me to reach the desktop screen. From there if I try to install Ubuntu, it seems to just hang forever after choosing a partition and beginning the install.

Additional searching and testing between different machines tells me that it is not an issue with the usb, but with the build - most likely motherboard BIOS options. I have a MSI Krait Gaming z170A 3x motherboard, and can't seem to find any options in the BIOS that would be preventing boot or installation. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Build Specs:

- CPU: Intel i7 6700k
- GPU: MSI GeForce GTX 970
- Motherboard: MSI Krait Gaming z170A 3x
- RAM: 32GB DDR4-2133
- Storage: Samsung EVO 840 120GB SSD